# Postgres - Grafana cpu,mem,wallclcok time how to convert to % and real time

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I am trying to put some metrics up on Grafana from a Postgres db.

On the Postgres database, I get the following values and I am not sure what statement is needed to convert them to % (for the cpu, mem usage).

And also how the value of the wallclock time could be converted to days,hours,min,sec

Image

[image]

Comment: Grafana is only the last step. To be able to really monitor postgresql you need to implement either "postgresql-exporter" + prometheus + Grafana or "Telegraf" + InfluxDB + Grafana. Otherwise you will not see any history of metrics.

Comment: Thank you for your help Jos, could you be more specific or provide links to get a better understanding?

Where would postgresql exporter and prometheus be installed and configured to be ready for grafana?

Comment: The postgres exporter supports Postgres 9.1 +             https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter

I am on 8.4.20 is there any other way to export my Postgres metrics to Prometheus?

Comment: OK, this is of course small complication but check Telegraf metrics collector (https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.5/plugins/inputs/). They declare in docs that it works with PG 8.1+. Telegraf sends data into InfluxDB timeseries database and this will be used as datasource for Grafana. We use this monitoring too and generally it works great. There is input plug-in "postgresql_extensible" which will allow you to use your specific queries like here - http://testing.freeideas.cz/subdom/testing/2017/09/11/monitor-postgresql-replication-lags-with-telegraf/

Comment: To monitor directly postgresql process use Telegraf input plug-in "procstat" - https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/procstat For me it works OK with PG pid file like in this example - [[inputs.procstat]]
  pid_file="/run/postgresql/9.6-main.pid"

Comment: Thanks a lot Jos opened up my eyes and gave me solutions.
I will try and implement them

Answer (score 0):

You can use axes as per below screenshot. it will show you percentage logically.
you can set min, max memory or other metric. For ex: you have 4 GB memory then select Unit: bits. Min:0, Max:4294967296 (bit of 4GB) then it will show you as per screenshot that if your process use, 345MB, it will fill graph respective percentage.

[image]